# The future tense (will / going to )?

Tags: grammar, future, linguistics, will-be-going, functions

Could anyone answer this then explain correctly?

> Choose :
>   Be careful, you ..... your hand with that knife .
>
> will cut / are going to cut /are cutting

Comment: They're all right.

Comment: why don't you show us that you at least TRIED to do your own homework.

Comment: But when it comes to a test which one should I choose?

Comment: I've already done but my teacher says it's (will) while another teacher says it's (are cutting )!!

Comment: The "answer" *you will cut your hand* sounds too formal, all the choices given should have the contracted form, because in speech we tend to say e.g. "I'll take care of it, I promise."; "*Be careful, you'll cut your hand*"; *"Careful! You're cutting yourself"*; and "*Be careful, you're going to cut yourself/your hand*"

Comment: I would have said that *"going to"* was the correct answer, because that's the form used for immediate warnings (which this looks like). Certainly, there's no justification for saying *"going to"* is wrong.

Comment: What explanations did your teachers give for preferring the "will cut" and "are cutting" to "going to cut"? I'm really curious to know.

Comment: Texts (unfortunately) often teach that "going to" is used for the "planned" future, while "will" is used for the unplanned. As a teacher, I'm painfully sure this is why "going to" can't be seen as right.

Comment: Compare, *I'm going to go shopping tomorrow* with (knock on door)--*I'll get it!*

Comment: Such texts usually teach "prediction with evidence" (going to), and "prediction without evidence" (will), similar to @shoe explains, but my experience tells me they are focusing on planned/unplanned. In this regard, present continuous is called "arranged" future, which puts the "are cutting" teacher the farthest out in wackyland.

Comment: If the OP is asking why a test (and teachers) may have asked the question, it seems as valid a qurstion as many. Perhaps better on ELL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the knife-wielder is actually in the process of cutting into her hand and somehow hasn't noticed, then:

> Be careful, you are cutting your hand!

is correct, using the *present progressive* for an action in progress.

However, if the speaker is predicting what will happen if the knife-wielder is not more careful, then both of the following are possible and common:

> 1. Be careful, you are going to cut your hand!
> 2. Be careful, you will cut your hand!

A subtle difference in the two forms may be detected. The *going to* prediction (1) is more of an immediate warning that the knife-holder is on the point of self-harm. The *will* prediction is more of a general warning that the knife-holder is becoming at risk of self-harm through increasingly careless movements.

There is evidence for the above assertion in the fact that you can replace *Be careful* with *Look out* in the *going to* prediction, but it sounds suspect in the *will* prediction.

> Look out! You're going to cut your hand!
>
> ?Look out! You will cut your hand!

Comment: This is like the example that Bob Binnick used in his paper "_Will_ and _Be Going To_", in CLS. His was _Watch out! That rock ...... fall!_ on a hiking trail, and of course _will_ is ridiculous here; it hasta be _gonna_.

Comment: It's obvious that the present would be denoted in the example present progressive, but we use the present progressive to talk about the future as well as *an action in progress.* (*I am going home after work. I am flying to London [next week].*)

Comment: @Jim, My sympathies are with the OP if one of his or her English teachers really believes that the progressive form is the correct choice in this context.

Comment: Yes, and a teacher does believe just that, according to the OP's comment. I made that comment only because many English learners, even many at higher levels, are surprised to hear that it *can* indicate the future. It often gets drilled in: *Subject is -ing RIGHT NOW.* It's so frustrating I'm cutting my whiteboard hand (next week) in protest.

Answer (score -1):

**Be careful, you will cut your hand** looks fine to me.

Comment: On EL&U we encouraged users to provide justification/rationale for their answers, and ideally references to external authorities.